# fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") - Error

Tags: python, image

When I try running this script:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

files = os.listdir('mri')
for file in files:
    img = Image.open(file)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resize_image.py", line 6, in <module>
    img = Image.open(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2258, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '6.jpg'
```

I made sure that 6.jpg is available. And, it seems that I get such error for any image in this location.

How can I fix the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure it's available _again_, because I can tell you right now that it isn't. Fix the issue by making absolutely sure that the file is there. Check working directories, absolute paths, and so on. Python didn't suddenly decide to lie to you and cover your file with a blanket to pretend it's not there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I really made sure that the image is available. I removed the image, and got the same error for the next image in the folder

Comment: That's not what I meant at all. It's not like one file will be wearing a camouflage suit but the rest are easily visible, so removing that first one and still getting a problem means that Python is lying to you. As I said, check what directory you think Python is looking in, and then check what directory it is actually looking in. Dan's answer below points out that you're using a relative path when the files are in another folder level.

Answer (score 2):

The file names from `os.listdir` are relative to the directory given. They must be made complete by joining the dirname to their basename.

```
files = os.listdir('my_folder')
for file in files:
    img = Image.open(os.path.join('my_folder', file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you haven't add your image in project file folder.
Paste your image in project file and then run the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join('mri', file))
```

this worked for me making sure you join the dir with the path

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Simin\Desktop\python proj\img.jpg'))
```

this direct path worked for me

Comment: There's no need to use `join` for the absolute path; have a look at the [`join` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score -1):

The image is incorrectly located in the folder you selected. It says Image.py and you want to open 6.jpg.

Comment: You forgot to share how to resolve the problem